# How do I pass two variables to via renderpartial to a control?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code which renders a control called ExchangeRates.ascx. I want to pass two variables to the control, currencyCode and toCurrencyCode but I only know how to pass one. Can anyone help?

```
        <% var currencyCode = Html.Encode(Model.Country.CurrencyCode);  %>  

        <% var toCurrencyCode = Html.Encode(Model.Country.toCurrencyCode);  %> 

        <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/ExchangeRates.ascx", currencyCode); %>
```

Comment: You can use ViewData to transfer any additional data into view.

Comment: In MVC 3 you can use ViewBag dynamic object, this is wrapper under ViewData but it's more usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a new model containing the two properties you are interested in:

```
public class CurrencyCodesViewModel
{
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public string ToCurrencyCode { get; set; }
}
```

and then strongly type your partial view to this model and pass an instance of it:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial(
    "~/Views/Shared/ExchangeRates.ascx", 
    new CurrencyCodesViewModel { 
        CurrencyCode = currencyCode, 
        ToCurrencyCode = toCurrencyCode
    }
); %>
```

Comment: You can't pass ananymous object instead of model to the strongly typed vie?

Comment: @Viacheslav, you are totally correct. Thanks. for pointing this out. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Viach: you can, but it won't be typed, and it's a lot of work to get it out again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case for `RenderPartial()` but for `RenderAction()` that returns a partial view.